# Cannot access oracle dba_directories from stored procedure

Tags: oracle

I am trying to access **DBA_DIRECTORIES** table  from a stored procedure using SYSTEM schema.But I am getting the following error

```
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

I can access the table from outside the stored procedure.The stored procedure is also under SYSTEM schema.How can i access the DBA_DIRECTORIES table from within a stored proc ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to access a view or a table that doesn't belong to you in a stored procedure, you need to have the necessary rights granted to you directly, not via a role:

So, have a DBA execute

```
grant all on dba_directories to <your_name>;
```

Then you should be able to access the view in your stored procedure.